# Change Microsoft Search to show current location in the path dialog box instead of "Search Results"

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, path, windows-server-2012-r2

There is a "feature" in Windows Search where after performing a search the subsequent  actions do not show the current path but instead shows a subset of the "Search Results" path.  This occurs when opening folders (see 2) or opening folders in new windows (see 3).

---

**Is there a way to make Windows Search show the path after navigating to a new folder instead of showing the path as a child of "Search Results"?**

It would make it *much* easier to copy-paste that path into documents or emails, and to know exactly where the file is located on the system.  Below is a series of screen shots showing the issue:

---

**1. Initial search for folder "Test" in folder "Virtual Machines" showing ["Search Results in Virtual Machines"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruf7Y.png)**

**2. Opening folder "Test" shows ["Test" as child of "Search Results"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eohvs.png)**

**3. Opening folder "Test" in new window shows ["Test" as child of "Search Results"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzlkE.png)**